# amazon web services -ebs snapshot - s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snapshot

I'm newbie in the cloud computing world.

I have a question about the backups. When we take an EBS snapshot is stored in amazon s3 ($0.095 per GB according the site).

For use this I need to contract amazon s3  service (with 500gb for example) in addition de ec2 and ebs or this automatically charged when I take a snapshot?

that's all. Bye.

UPDATE ------------

Sorry. Maybe my question was not enough well explained.

I will try to be more clear.
How I said, I read

from here http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/?nc2=h_ls

From the text I understand this: The snapshots are incremental and we must to pay for each gb/month $0.095. the snapshots are saved in Amazon s3.

My question come because I'm trying to use the amazon calculator. In the amazon calculator in the left corner I see the option Amazon S3, where I can reserve an amount of storage. Per example 500GB.

My doubt : Where will be saved the snapshots? in the Amazon s3 storage reserved by myself (500GB) ? Are discounted from the storage of my ebs? or are saved in a new Amazon S3 storage, independent of the 500gb S3 reserved?

In other words:

Is mandatory reserve "Amazon S3" storage for save snapshots or the needed space to keep all my snapshots are automaticly consumed without need of specify an "Amazon s3" storage?

I hope I was more clear, and sorry if my question is silly. Sorry for my english. Is still too rough. Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshots are performed behind the scene so there's no need to do anything with S3 directly.

You'll be paying for the first snapshot and diffs moving forward so the estimator is really just that, a simple estimation of storage cost for snapshots.